# msal angular changing scopes to lowercase fixed in 1.3.4

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I've encountered the bug in 1.3.3 where [MSAL is converting scopes to lowercase](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/1945). I see that it's fixed in 1.3.4/1.4.0 but those [don't have release dates attached to them](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/milestone/32). Do we know when the planned BETA/Release dates are? If not, are there any workarounds currently?

Answer (score 0):

We've been busy with some other work items, but we'll make sure this gets released soon! Sorry for the delay.

Comment: no problem, thanks for the great work @jasonnutter and team.